# Does having the company slogan at the top of every page hurt page rank

Tags: duplicate-content, pagerank

At the top of every page I have an image file with a graphic of the company logo. Next to it is the text for the company slogan in a span tag. below that is the top level menu and below that is an h1 tag containing the page topic including our primary long tail keyword phrase.

Is  having the company slogan at the top of every page bad for SEO since it is duplicate content? any google search for  our primary long tail keyword phrase lists our home page on the first page of google results so it cant be too awful, but a couple competitors are  higher up on page one so we want to do everything possible to improve our rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate content is duplicate **content**.

Google uses the HTML DOM model of more than one page to determine what HTML elements are repeated in an effort to separate the page header, footer, and any sidebars from content. This is a very easy thing to do.

*Having said that, anything within the header will not be counted as content.*

Comment: -Sounds like the company slogan is in the header and that is supported by the high page rank so it seems I should leave it as is.

Comment: @user204427 I certainly do not think it does you any harm! Though depending upon the slogan, it may return search users that do not match what you offer. I would be willing to bet that would be a very small number if at all. Something to look for in your log file analyzer.

Comment: @user204427 BTW- not sure why the down vote. So I up-voted to balance it all out for you. ;-) Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely solely on a one-line slogan to make your page rank high.

What you want to achieve is unique content on every page, and make sure each page is rich with text-based content so that people who can't see images or that use screen readers can understand the page.

While the slogan on every page counts as duplicate content, the impact wont be as high if each page has unique text with at least a few hundred words. If however your pages consist of what you described in your question (aka template) along with just one unique image for each page with the same "template" then you'll run into severe duplicate content and thin content problems because search engine robots can't convert images into text it can understand for search engine indexing.

Make sure when you revise your pages, you run them through a site that checks the amount of duplicate content for you. Doing a search on Google should give you some sites.

And just because you might have hit high in search engine results today doesn't mean you will tomorrow. Sign up for Google webmaster tools if you haven't done so to see what keywords users use to access your site from Google. As a bonus, in the HTML improvements section of webmaster tools, Google can indicate if you have duplicate title and meta description tags.